# Выборка отсутствующих записей по условию

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  department varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE history (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  employee_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  startJob datetime(0) NOT NULL,
  endJob datetime(0),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Две таблицы, связь один ко многим.
Как выбрать сотрудников, у которых нету записей в таблице history за определенный период startJob >= ? ... endJob <= ?

Comment: Левое соединение таблицы сотрудников с запросом, отбирающим записи за период из таблицы истории + employee_id IS NULL.

Comment: SELECT * FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN (SELECT employee_id from history h2 WHERE h2.startjob >= '2017-02-15' AND h2.endjob < '2017-02-20') ON e.id = h2.employee_id
WHERE e.id is NULL
что не так ?

Comment: Еще можно not exists использовать, для понимания гораздо проще, как звучит условие так и записывается `select * from employees where not exists(select 1 from history h where h.id=e.id and ...)`

Comment: @A.grin Подзапрос не имеет имени. Если он называется h2, тогда нужно написать h2.employee_id IS NULL.
Написал в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM employees e LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT employee_id from history WHERE startjob >= '2017-02-15' AND endjob < '2017-02-20') h2 ON e.id = h2.employee_id 
WHERE h2.employee_id is NULL
```